# django comparing datetime.time from Time fields - Type Error

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I am trying to compare two datetime.time variables in some python code in a View.

p_obj.time_start is a Time field

b_obj.time_start is also a Time field

```
slot_start = p_obj.time_start
whereami = slot_start
...
for b_obj in mydata:
   while (b_obj.time_start > whereami):
   ...
...
```

When I run the view, I get a Type Error
can't compare datetime.time to builtin_function_or_method

Looking at the django debug I can see that:

```
whereami    is <built-in method time of datetime.datetime object at 0x7fdb1136ee40>
```

but

```
slot_start  is  datetime.time(10, 0)
```

I believe my problem is due to the way the comparision is evaluating.

I have tried various permutations, and while I can get both variables independently to resolve to a datetime.time (like slot_start is) I can't see to get them both to  do it prior to or during the while comparison. Is there a way to force the evaluation prior to the comparison?

I have a thought that this might be something to do with the first method being evaluated then the result (a datetime.time) not being comparable to the second method (which is a method). Is there some simple syntax I am missing to make both elements evaluate prior to the comparison?

Strangely

```
if  (whereami < b_obj.time_start):
```

doesn't throw any error, and does appear to work correctly (in that it performs the expected comparisons).

Adding more info as requested:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    ....
    practavail = models.ForeignKey(PractAvail, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=False)
    time_start = models.TimeField("Start Time", blank=False)
    time_finish = models.TimeField("Finish Time", blank=False)
    ....

class PractAvail(models.Model):
    ....
    time_start = models.TimeField("Start Time", blank=False)
    time_finish = models.TimeField("Finish Time", blank=False)
    ....
```

Then in my view (skipping non essential bits):

```
p_avails = PractAvail.objects.filter(date=inputdate).order_by('time_start')
for p_obj in p_avails:
    mydata['bookings'][p_obj.pk] =  p_obj.booking_set.all().order_by('time_start')

    for b_obj in mydata['bookings'][p_obj.pk]:
```

and then the while loop as above.

I have also found that my code works fine with:

```
           if (b_obj.time_start > whereami):
               yesdoloop = True
           else:
               yesdoloop = False
           while yesdoloop:
              ...do stuff, including updating whereami...
              if (b_obj.time_start > whereami):
                    yesdoloop = True
              else:
                    yesdoloop = False
```

So, there is definitely something different about how a while compares as against how an if compares (I think?!)

Comment: How is `p_obj` created/fetched from the database? Please show your models and the full traceback.

Comment: sorry - can't add the traceback right now... life calls - but thank you for the interest, will revert code to recreate tomorrow morning (unless the edit above is useful in itself?)

Comment: I guess you are modifying whereami in the while loop. Please show up what you are doing un this loop.

Comment: `thisavailend = (datetime.combine(datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0),whereami) + timedelta(seconds=900)).time()`
`whereami =  thisavailend`

Comment: Are you sure you didn't miss the `()` after `.time`? That's what the error suggests.

Comment: @antoine ah.... so you mean the Type Error could have been in the second `while` evaluation, not the first time around... you know, it's quite possible... I certainly continued to debug and improve the code as soon as I'd put the replacement `if` in. I'm still not clear why the if didn't cause an error when the 'while' did - but yeah maybe I got a bit confused there... Now the rest of the loop is sane, I'll revert to the `while` and see if it's working now...I had just **assumed** it was the first while evaluation - but yeah - could well have been the second...

Comment: @antoine - yep.. I think that was it. Mystery solved. Thanks :)